# With so much system resources available, how sure are you your code is tuned?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic

With CPUs being increasingly faster, hard disks spinning, bits flying around so quickly, network speeds increasing as well, it's not that simple to tell bad code from good code like it used to be.

I remember a time when you could optimize a piece of code and undeniably perceive an improvement in performance.  Those days are almost over.  Instead, I guess we now have a set of rules that we follow like "Don't declare variables inside loops" etc.  It's great to adhere to these so that you write good code by default.  But how do you know it can't be improved even further without some tool?

Some may argue that a couple of nanoseconds won't really make that big a difference these days.  The truth is, we are stuck with so many layers that you get a staggering effect.

I'm not saying we should optimize every little millisecond out of our code as that will be expensive and unfeasible.  I believe we have to do our best, given our time constraints, to write efficient code as well.

**I'm just interested to know what tools you use to profile and measure performance of code, if at all.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a big difference between "good" code and "fast" code. They aren't exactly separate from each other either, but "fast" code doesn't mean "good". Often times, "fast" actually means bad code because readability compromises must be made to make it fast.

The way I look at it, [hardware is cheap, programmers are expensive](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001198.html). Unless there is a serious performance problem with some piece of code, you should never have to worry about speed. If there are performance problems, you'll notice them. Only when you notice the performance problem on good hardware should you have to worry about optimization (in my opinion)

If you reach the point where your code is slow, but you can't figure out why, I'd use a profiler like [ANT](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm), or [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) if you're in the .NET world (I'm sure there are others out there for other platforms & languages). They're pretty useful, but I've only ever had one situation where I needed a profiler to identify the problem. It was something that now that I know the issue, I won't need a profiler again to tell me it's a problem because I'll never forget the amount of time I spent trying to optimize it.

Answer (score 4):

I think that optimization should be thought of not as looking at each line of code, but rather, what asymptotic complexity is your algorithm.  For example, using a bubble sort is probably one of the worst sorting algorithms you could use in terms of optimization.  It takes the longest.  Quicksort and mergesort are faster in terms of sorting, and should be always used before a bubble sort.

If you keep optimization always in your mind when designing a solution to a problem, then you should be able to write readable code, which other developers will approve of.  Also, if you are programming in a higher level language that will be compiled before it is run, remember that compilers make some awesome optimizations nowadays that you or I may not think of, and also (more importantly) do not have to worry about.

Stick with a good and low big O(), and it should be optimized pretty good.  If you are working with millions or greater in some type of dataset, then look for a big O(logn) algorithm.  They work great for large tasks, and keep your code optimized.

Let the compilers work on the line by line code optimizations so you can focus on the solutions.

There are times that do warrant line by line optimizations, and if that is the case that you need that much speed, maybe you might want to look into assembly so that you can control every line that is written.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely a valid concern, but not for most developers.  Most developers are concerned with getting a product that works to their employer.  Optimized code is seldom a requirement.

The best way to make sure your code is fast is to benchmark or profile it.  A lot of compiler optimizations create non-intuitive oddities in the performance of a programmer's code, so in the end measurement becomes essential.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, [Rational Quantify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/quantify/support/) has given me the best results in terms of code tuning.  It is not free, but it is very fully featured and seems to have given me the most useful results.

In terms of free tools, check out [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html) or [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/), if you are on a Unix environment. They are not as good as some of the commercial tools, but can often point you in the right direction.

On a side note, I am almost always surprised at what profilers turn up the first time I use them. You can have intuition as to where code may be bottlenecking, and it can often be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all code I write is plenty fast enough.  On the rare occasions when it isn't, for C, C++, and Objective Caml I use the venerable `gprof` and the excellent [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) with its superb visualizer [`kcachegrind`](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdesdk-apidocs/kcachegrind/html/index.html) (part of the KDE SDK; don't be fooled by the out-of-date code on sourceforge).

The [MLton](http://mlton.org) Standard ML compiler and the [Glasgow Haskell Compiler](http://haskell.org/ghc) both ship with excellent profilers.

I wish there were a better profiler for [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Uh, a profiler maybe? There are ones available for almost all platforms and languages.